# Generate xml from ms sql with head and item tables

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'd like to generate an xml from MS SQL with a structure like this (invoice head info, then invoice items info):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-2"?>
<Data HD="1" View="InvoiceGen">
    <Row Table="InvoiceHead">
        <InvoiceNumber>630506</InvoiceNumber>
        <CustomerId>1432</CustomerId>
    </Row>
    <Row Table="InvoiceItem">
        <ItemNumber>B52</ItemNumber>
        <Price>320</Price>
        <Tax>30</Tax>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ItemNumber>B53</ItemNumber>
        <Price>330</Price>
        <Tax>32</Tax>
    </Row>
    <Row Table="InvoiceHead">
        <InvoiceNumber>630626</InvoiceNumber>
        <CustomerId>1556</CustomerId>
    </Row>
    <Row Table="InvoiceItem">
        <ItemNumber>B5</ItemNumber>
        <Price>500</Price>
        <Tax>55</Tax>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ItemNumber>B5</ItemNumber>
        <Price>200</Price>
        <Tax>20</Tax>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ItemNumber>B18</ItemNumber>
        <Price>180</Price>
        <Tax>16</Tax>
    </Row>
</Data>
```

i have an invoice head table, and an invoice item table (InvoiceNumer makes the connection between the two):

InvoiceHead (InvoiceNumber,CustomerId)

InvoiceItem (InvoiceNumber,ItemNumber,Price,Tax)

I have already created a table with the combined data, with the same structure as in the desired xml:

InvoiceGen(InvoiceNumber,CustomerId,ItemNumber,Price,Tax)

In this table, after a head row there are all the rows with the item information connected to the invoice head. (Just like in the xml)

The contet of this InvoiceGen table is:

```
InvoiceNumber   CustomerId  ItemNumber  Price   Tax
630506          1432        null        null    null
630506          1432        B52         320     30
630506          1432        B53         330     32
630626          1556        null        null    null
630626          1556        B5          500     55
630626          1556        B6          200     20
630626          1556        B18         180     16
```

I'm not sure if this table can help me, but it looked like a good idea.

Can anyone help me to create an xml like the above?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look at `FOR XML PATH`?

Comment: Yes, i have. ive already generated many xml documents but this looks a bit over my knowledge

Comment: Also, why do 5 of your rows have values of `NULL` for `InvoiceNumber` and `CustomerID`, and the other 2 `NULL` for the item's details? Can these items be display under any order, therefore? Otherwise, with that data, how do we return the same data set with the use of an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: if the invoice numer is not null, then that is a head row. After every head row, the item rows follow for that invoice.
The Invoice number and CustomerID can be filled if needed in the item rows as well.

Comment: Rows don't "follow" in SQL Server; they're stored in heaps. There's nothing, in your data, that defines what row "follows" another. We need a value for the order of the rows, or something, in the data.

Comment: you are right. corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically gets you to what you want. Note, however, that `'B18'` is sorted **before** `'B5'` and `'B6'` because your values are `varchar`s. With a `varchar` the value `'1'` and a lower value than `'5'`, and so `'18'` as a "lower" value than `'5'`:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (630506,1432,NULL,NULL,NULL),
                 (630506,1432,'B52',320,30),
                 (630506,1432,'B53',330,32),
                 (630626,1556,NULL,NULL,NULL),
                 (630626,1556,'B5',500 ,55),
                 (630626,1556,'B6',200,20),
                 (630626,1556,'B18',180,16)) V(InvoiceNumber,CustomerID,ItemNumber,Price,Tax))
SELECT 1 aS [@HD],
       'InvoiceGen' AS [@View],
       (SELECT CASE WHEN ItemNumber IS NULL THEN 'InvoiceHead' ELSE 'InvoiceItem' END AS [@Table],
               CASE WHEN ItemNumber IS NULL THEN InvoiceNumber END AS InvoiceNumber,
               CASE WHEN ItemNumber IS NULL THEN CustomerID END AS CustomerID,
               ItemNumber,
               Price,
               Tax
        FROM VTE V
        ORDER BY V.InvoiceNumber,
                 V.CustomerID,
                 CASE WHEN V.ItemNumber IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                 V.ItemNumber
        FOR XML PATH('Row'),TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('Data');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to make some minor modification, but it works properly!

Comment: Glad to hear it @petibaucsi. Please do mark it as the solution if it helped you so that future readers know that the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: i did, but got this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @petibaucsi mark it as the solution (the tick), to show the answer provided the solution.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)